# "Else " without a previous "If"

Tags: c++

There are many questions like this but none could help me with this.
So like the title says it says else without a previous if.
Tried to build a program that will count the numbers from 1-1000 that can be divided by 2.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    a=1;
    while(a<=1000)
       if(a%2==0)
         cout<<a;
         a++;
       else
         a++;

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put braces wherever needed.

Comment: Use braces `{}`!

Comment: To be clear, the result of `if(a%2==0)` is `cout<<a;` Then you say `a++;
       else` and the compiler correctly says that `else` is not valid after `a++;`

Comment: Why not take `a++;` out of the if/else completely and have only `cout<<a;` as part of the if-block? (btw if you do that, you'll need braces for the `while` loop.)

Comment: In fact, why not just write a `for` loop, since that's what you seem to be implementing?

Answer (score 12):

C++ is not Python - whitespace doesn't change the behavior of the program. To make both `cout<<a` and `a++` belong to the `if`'s true-branch body, you need to enclose them in curly braces to create a [compound statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Compound_statements):

```
if(a%2==0)
{
    cout<<a;
    a++;
}
else
{
    a++;
}
```

Comment: Also note that g++ and probably clang now outputs a warning when it sees such unmatched indent.

Comment: @Asu huh? What warning? It's an error without the braces, and it's perfectly fine with them.

Comment: @bolov: if there was no `else` branch, a warning would be shown to inform the user that both indented instructions are not part of the if's body.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the programming languages if - else statements works for only one statement if there are no braces. So use braces.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  int main()
 {
   int a;
   a=1;
   while(a<=1000)
   if(a%2==0){
     cout<<a;
     a++;
   }else{
     a++;
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this must be replaced or corrected  by using braces {}

```
 if(a%2==0)
         cout<<a;
         a++;
       else
         a++;
```

C++ is not an indented compiled language

do instead :

```
if( a%2 == 0)
{
  cout<<a;
  a++;
}else{
  a++;
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't actually need the else just : if( a%2 == 0)
{
  cout<<a;
}  a++;

Answer (score 0):

First, it is unclear what the problem is. If you're asking whether `else`'s can be placed after something which is not an `if` statement then no, the purpose of `else` is to execute code when an `if`'s condition is false. If you want to know what is wrong with the program, you need to use `{}` braces. A for loop would be better for this:

```
for(int a = 1;a<=1000;a++){
    if((a%2)==0){
        cout<<a<<' ';
    }
}
```

You also forgot to print a space after printing `a`, you should fix that too.

Answer (score 0):

Like other answer: use braces... and factorize: if all you are doing (`a++`) in the `else` is the same than in the second part of the `if`, then you may rewrite your main as is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  while (a<=1000) {
    if (a%2==0) {
      cout<<a;
    }
    ++a;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Or, because that's the purpose of the `for` loop:

```
  for (int a = 1; i <= 1000; ++a) {
    if (a%2==0) {
      cout << a;
    }
  }
```